# Erro na configuração do postgres com wildfly

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, wildfly

Realizei a configuração do postgresql:

C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\postgresql\main

Adicionei os arquivos:
module.xml
postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar

OBS:
O banco tem a versão 9.6 e o drive 9.4, será que o problema pode ser este?

Erro:

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "Multlevel")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0042: failed to match pool. Check JndiName: java:jboss/datasources/multlevel",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

```
Arquivo module

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar"/>
        <!-- Make sure this matches the name of the JAR you are installing -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

```
Arquivo Standalone:

<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/multlevel" pool-name="Multlevel" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/estoquecd</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                         <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                         <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                         <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>

                <drivers>

        <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>

                </drivers>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava no local da pasta do drive
name="org.postgresql"

De acordo com a configuração o caminho correto seria:
C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\postgres\main